# how to manipulate returned mongo collections / cursors in javascript (meteor.js)?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, coffeescript, meteor

In working with Meteor.js and Mongo I use the find({*some arguments*}) and sometimes find({*some arguments*}).fetch() to return cursors and an array of matching documents respectively.

What is the real difference between the two? (when would I use one versus the other?)

What is the proper way to manipulate/iterate over these type of returned objects?

E.g. 
I have a collection that has many documents each with a title field.

My goal was to get an array of all the title fields' values e.g. [doc1title,doc2title,doc3title]

I did this:

```
var i, listTitles, names, _i, _len;
names = Entries.find({}).fetch();
listTitles = [];
for (_i = 0, _len = names.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    i = names[_i];
    listTitles.push(i.title);
}
```

or the equivalent in coffeescript

```
names = Entries.find({}).fetch()
listTitles = []
for i in names
    listTitles.push(i.title)
```

which works, but I have no idea if its the proper way or even a semi sane way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your first question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601957/meteor-use-fetch-or-find-in-template-helper-functions) - also see [this](http://projectricochet.com/blog/meteor-js-performance) post. The short answer is that you want to use the cursor returned by `find` unless you really need all of the data at once in order to manipulate it before sending it to a template.

Your CoffeeScript could be rewritten as:

```
titles = (entry.title for entry in Entries.find().fetch())
```

If you are using underscore, it could also be written as:

```
titles = _.pluck Entries.find().fetch(), 'title'
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to the meteor docs. As a side note, why oh why did they invent the name fetch() for creating an array from a cursor when it is called toArray() in normal Mongo. It took me a good while to figure out that I did not possess a normal Mongo cursor but instead a meteor variant.

Answer (score 11):

To iterate over a cursor in js simply use [cursor.forEach](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/foreach)

```
const cursor = Collection.find();
cursor.forEach(function(doc){
  console.log(doc._id);
});
```

When converting cursors to arrays you will also find the [.map()](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-map) function useful:

```
const names = Entries.find();
let listTitles = names.map(doc => { return doc.title });
```